# ESP32 simulate a current transformer

Tags: current, schematics, current-measurement, esp32

I currently have a current transformer that generate a 0 to 0.7 V AC voltage (in my case) when reading. It is actually an SCT013A current transformer.

I would need to simulate it using ESP32, so basically create a 50 Hz PWM signal that can vary from 0 to 0.7V over time.

My idea is use another pin to create the desired voltage, for example 0.65 V, by an analogwrite for the PWM generation but I have no idea on how to create it by a schematics.

Could someone move me in the right schematics direction or have an alternative idea?

Comment: _”0 to 0.7 V AC current”_ That would be voltage, not current. Is you end goal to be able to set a 50 Hz sine wave amplitude between 0 and 0.7 V?

Comment: hello, yes sorry I wrote bad.

Comment: Is this a one-off? If yes, I would consider letting the ESP32 generate the 50 Hz waveform at 0 dBFS, AC-couple via a capacitor and having an VCA do the heavy lifting of scaling it to your desired value. Otherwise, a slow but high-bit ADC would do the job as well.

Comment: hi winny, what you mean for VCA ?

Comment: Voltage controlled amplifier.